# Selecting nested CSS classes

Tags: html, css

I would like to understand some behaviour I am experiencing with CSS class selection.

I am attempting to reference only css classes `line-1` that are used as children of two separate parent classes. The first instance also has an additional classname. Which you can see below. Basically I need to select all of the `.line-1` classes. Both have different parents `.row icon explainBlah` & `.row icon`.

**index.html**

```
<div class="row icon explainBlah">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox long">
      <div class="title">1</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">blah blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox long">
      <div class="title">2</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">blah blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox long">
      <div class="title">3</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">blah blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox long">
      <div class="title">4</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">blah blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row icon">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox"><img src="images/icons/smartphone.svg" alt="smartphone.svg" height="30">
      <div class="title">Mobile</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">Blah 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox"><img src="images/icons/wheel@2x.png" alt="wheel@2x.png" height="30">
      <div class="title">Efficiency</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">Blah 2 <strong> Blah 2 </strong> Blah 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox"><img src="images/icons/stop@2x.png" alt="stop@2x.png" height="30">
      <div class="title">No discovery</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">Blah 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="featureBox"><img src="images/icons/frame@2x.png" alt="frame@2x.png" height="30">
      <div class="title">Clarity</div>
      <div class="line-1"></div>
      <div class="description">Blah 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have managed to successfully select **both** child instances of the `.line-1` elements as per the first example:

**index.styl**

```
.featureBox.long, .row.icon .featureBox
    .line-1
        max-width 160px
```

but I was surprised when **this** didn't work for the second `.featureBox` set of elements:

**index.styl**

```
.featureBox.long, .featureBox
    .line-1
        max-width 160px
```

Seeing as a direct reference `.featureBox.long` worked, why doesn't `.featureBox` and why do I have to use `.row.icon .featureBox` as in the first example?

**Solution**

Very simple:

```
.row.icon .featureBox
    .line-1
        max-width 180px
```

The inclusion of more 'specific' selectors i.e. `.row.icon .featureBox.long` above would invalidate `.row.icon .featureBox`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've read your question thrice and still don't know what the issue is

Comment: Direct use `.featureBox` to select all.

Comment: There was a mistake - Please see the new version

Comment: If you're just trying to target all instances of elements with the class `line-1` why include the parent classes at all? Just target `.line-1` in your CSS.

Comment: because it's just the children that need targeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the first class selection and use only the second.

```
.row.icon .featureBox .line-1 {
    //selects .line-1 of every .featureBox element that is a child of .row.icon
}


.row.icon .featureBox.long .line-1 {
    //selects .line-1 every .featureBox  element that is a child of .row.icon and has an extra class of .long
}
```

By including the `.row.icon` you're making the selector more specific so will hold a higher priority over other styles applied to the `.featureBox`

Comment: But he says he is targeting `line-1`.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron - As per your explanation, it does turns out that a more specific selector will take precedence over more general ones, and (surprisingly) invalidates them - the solution I used is in my question

Comment: @Stussy you will also find that the position of the selector in your CSS will effect it's precedence too. For example if you have `.line {font-size: 12px}` at the top of the CSS and below it you have another `.line {font-size: 16px}` the 2nd set (16px) will override the 1st set (12px)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple target ".line-1" instead of going by the hierarchy, as you wish to style all the elements with class="line-1" itself.